# Internacionalizar web app com jQuery i18n plugin

Tags: jquery, i18n

Estou tentando utilizar [este](https://github.com/wikimedia/jquery.i18n) plugin jQuery para internacionalizar minha web app.

Especificamente, estou querendo utilizar a API data nos campos que devem ser traduzidos mas o `alert` retorna "um" e não "ONE" e as tags spans continuam com Um e Dois.

**Página**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>jQuery i18n Demo</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="../src/jquery.i18n.js"></script>
<script src="../src/jquery.i18n.messagestore.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $.i18n({
        locale: 'en'
    });

    alert($.i18n("um"));
</script>
</head>

<body>
<span data-i18n="um">Um</span>.
<span data-i18n="dois">Dois</span>.
</body>
</html>
```

**en.json**

```
{
"um": "ONE",
"dois": "TWO"
}
```

Alguém já utilizou ele e pode ajudar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para fazer com que o código execute e realize a internacionalização é necessário invocar a função `$.i18n()` nos elementos desejados. Para utilizar de forma genérica (em todos os elementos com o atributo data-i18n), utilize o seletor `[data-i18n]`.

O código pode ser executado da seguinte forma: `$('[data-i18n]').i18n()`.

## Exemplo

Segue abaixo um exemplo demonstrando o uso do plugin

```js
$.i18n().load({
  br: {
    'welcome': 'ola mundo'
  },
  en: {
    'welcome': 'hello world'
  },
  es: {
    'welcome': 'hola mundo'
  }
});

function changeLocale(locale) {

  $.i18n({
    locale: locale
  });

  $('[data-i18n]').i18n();

}

$(function() {

  $('button').on('click', function() {

    var locale = $(this).data('locale');

    changeLocale(locale);

  });

});

changeLocale('en'); // locale default da página
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://thottingal.in/projects/js/jquery.i18n/src/jquery.i18n.js"></script>
<script src="http://thottingal.in/projects/js/jquery.i18n/src/jquery.i18n.messagestore.js"></script>


<button type="button" data-locale="br">br</button>
<button type="button" data-locale="en">en</button>
<button type="button" data-locale="es">es</button>

<h1 data-i18n="welcome">ola mundo (fallback)</h1>
```

Comment: O mesmo da para fazer utilizando as properties em Java, você coloca `label.teste=Teste` e utilizando o Spring você chama a chave `label.teste` para aparecer o texto, portanto, qual a vantagem e desvantagem de utilizar tanto um quanto o outro? Pode-se utilizar os dois na mesma aplicação? Seria uma boa prática?

Comment: @GiancarloGiulian praticamente todo framework MVC (Struts, JSF, Spring MVC) trabalha com i18n. A diferença principal é que utilizando a i18n desse modo, o back-end vai enviar o HTML já com o resultado da internacionalização. Caso o usuário deseje alterar o idioma, o framework vai realizar uma nova requisição para recuperar o HTML novamente. Utilizando o plugin do jquery a responsabilidade da internacionalização é da camada front-end. As alterações podem ou não realizar uma nova requisição, dependendo da implementação. Para a grande maioria dos casos, apenas uma das soluções já vai atender bem.

Comment: Obrigado @Romulo, se conseguir listar mais vantagens e desvantagens de utilizar um ou outro agradeceria novamente.

Comment: Como a opção de idioma fica armazenada em banco e posteriormente em session (após login), o que acha de eu criar um .js para cada idioma (en.js e pt.js) já com o código de inicialização (seu método changeLocale) e adicioná-los na página de acordo com a session dele?

Comment: @Onaiggac parece uma opção completamente funcional