# Tradução de conteúdo de website estático para 4 idiomas

Tags: javascript, jquery, i18n

Qual a ferramenta que vocês têm utilizado para liberar a opção de tradução do conteúdo de um site estático em HTML para outro idioma?
Algum plugin jquery, alguma api?
Qual é a melhor prática visando desempenho atualmente?

Será que o ideal seria usar algo que capture o IP do usuário e carregue uma página já traduzida no idioma para aquele país?

Serão apenas 4 idiomas: Português, Inglês, Espanhol e Italiano. 
Para o restante dos países, o idioma padrão poderá ser o inglês.

Comment: Uma vez pesquisei a mesma coisa e cheguei ate esse [i18next](http://i18next.com/docs) que parece fazer exatamente o que precisa somente com JS. Nao cheguei a usar pois foi decidido nao tem 2 idiomas.

Comment: Da uma olhada neste plugin http://www.openxrest.com/translatejs/

Comment: Pode dar uma olha em: [Como traduzir um site em PHP?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15937/91), [Como tornar um site multilíngue?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21788/91), [Site em dois idiomas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110553/91) e [Como tornar um site multilíngue e identificar o país de origem?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30982/91)

Comment: Com javascript tem essa => [Internacionalizar web app com jQuery i18n plugin](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88624/91)

Comment: para identificar o pais utilizando jquery vc pode ver essa resposta no SO EN http://stackoverflow.com/a/28960373/3155576, ele indica o código 

$.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/', function(result) {
  alert(result.country_code);
});

testei a URL e ele trouxe certinho

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer toda tradução via gulp, tem uns módulos interessantes de i18n https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-static-i18n

Você precisa de um módulo no gulp que leia seus textos ou elementos html com determinado atributo data/class e que esse módulo jogue tudo num json ou arquivo .mo(muito usado para tradução)

E outra task para buildar as traduções, duplicando os htmls e trocando os textos, assim você poderia subir tudo em um servidor estático do tipo S3 da amazon, que tem baixo custo e assim você não precisa de um server/backend para traduzir texto, é escalável e rápido.

E para o redirect via geolocalizção, talvez dê para fazer via nginx ou htacces, então você precisa de um server só para fazer o redirect, então você terá isso:

User acessa o site *->* server com nginx que verifica a língua e redireciona para o path certo do S3 *->* S3 com folder */en/* ou */pt/* ou */es/* ou outra *língua/pasta*.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que uma das melhores formas é usar o `link`, como:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-gb" href="http://en-gb.site.com" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="pt-br" href="http://pt-br.site.com" />
```

Isso já vai fazer com que os buscadores já mostrem o conteúdo na linguagem certa, na maioria dos casos.

Mas, obviamente isso não é suficiente. Para obter a linguagem do usuário, uma boa maneira é obter o `window.navigator.language`, então usar algum tipo de *matcher* de *BCP-47*, assim se o resultado do navegador for `en-us` ele iria obter o idioma mais próximo disponível, o `en-gb`, por exemplo. Se não houver um idioma *próximo* cairá num padrão, que é o que você define.

---

Esta é a primeira vez que tento fazer um site com multiplos idiomas, então o que vou escrever aqui é o que estou fazendo, mas não foi "testado em produção" e talvez haja outros problemas nesse método.

> Estou usando o GopherJS, Golang, portanto apenas copiei o que uso e tentei simplificar, mas será necessário achar funções equivalentes para Javascript.

O que tenho feito é simplesmente:

```
<div data-text="welcome"></div>
```

Então, ao iniciar a página se obtêm a linguagem do cliente, usando  o `window.navigator.language`, e existe um dicionário e a lista de idiomas:

```
var Idiomas = []language.Tag{language.English, language.BrazilianPortuguese}

var Dicionario = texts{
    "welcome": {
       "Welcome",
       "Bem-vindo",
    },
    "another-text": {
        "Another text",
        "Outro texto",
    },
}
```

Agora, para saber qual conteúdo exibir, eu utilizo o [`text/language`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/language), você deverá achar algum outro para o Javascript. Dessa forma simplesmente se torna:

```
var idiomaEscolhido string

// Obtêm o idioma do subdominio, se existir
subdominio := strings.Split(js.Global.Get("location").Get("host").String(), ",")
if len(subdominio) > 1 && subdominio[0] != "meusite" {
    idiomaEscolhido = subdominio[0]
}   

// Obtêm o idioma do navegador, se não há definido até então
if idiomaUsuario = "" {
    idiomaUsuario = js.Global.Get("navigator").Get("language").String()
}

// Encontra o idioma mais próximo
 _, index := language.MatchStrings(language.NewMatcher(AvailableLanguages), lang)
```

O `index` representa `0` para `language.English` e `1` para `language.BrazilianPortuguese`. Primeiro usamos o idioma do subdominio (como `en-us.meusite.com`), mas se não existir um subdominio (como `meusite.com`) iremos usar o idioma do navegador. Então, quando carregar a página basta fazer um:

```
for _, el := range t.QuerySelectorAll("[data-text]") {

    text, ok := Dicionario[el.GetAttribute("data-text")][index]
    if !ok == "" {
        logs.Warn("Não encontramos textos para " + el.GetAttribute("data-text"))
    }

    t.SetText(el, text)
}
```

A ideia deste código é obter todos os `data-text` e substituir. Então, se houver `data-text="welcome"` ele deve pegar o texto que está no mapa do `dicionario`. Então, o `dicionario["welcome"][0]` será o inglês, e o `dicionario["welcome"][1]` será o português.

Isso tem algumas limitações, como formatações de datas ou plurais. Por exemplo, no Brasil, usamos `DD/MM/AAAA`, enquanto em outros lugares é `MM/DD/AAAA.` Uma maneira de mitigar isso é usando um padrão internacional, mas isso pode ser estranho em alguns casos.

---

Já no lado da performance, há como mitigar o impacto. Uma vez que você tem que encontrar todos os `data-text` e então realizar a inserção do texto, você pode usar o HTMLTemplateElement (o `<template>`) ou o HTMLSlotElement (o `<slot>`). Esses dois elementos não são renderizados, exceto quando iniciados. Isso indica que todos os `data-text` dentro dele não será traduzido e não será obtido. Então, a cada vez que for exibir um `template` terá que traduzir o texto contido nele.

Isso reduz o impacto, já que apenas o que foi iniciado será traduzido. Então, apenas o que o usuário ver será traduzido, não perderá tempo traduzindo aquilo que o usuário não vai ver.

---

Já na parte do SEO, você pode realizar o mesmo do JS no lado do servidor. O objetivo aqui é simples. Quando o usuário acessar `en-us.site.com` o bot já vai ver o conteúdo em inglês, então todos os `data-text` já vão estar preenchidos antecipadamente, mesmo que o cliente não tenha o Javascript.

Para isso, é possível criar, no meu caso, um `http.Handle`, nele irá executar um código usando o `htmlquery`, que usa o XPATH. Então, cria um arquivo `index_en_us.html` e `index_pt_bt.html`, ambos tem o conteúdo os `data-text` já preenchido e já previamente armazenado.

Quando o usuário acessar `en-us.site.com` ele será servido por `index_en_us.html`. Porém, se ele clicar em "Português", os efeitos serão imediatos e não precisará esperar uma requisição para o `pt-br.site.com`, já que a tradução também pode ser feita no cliente.

*Caso utilize o NodeJS poderá fazer a mesma coisa, talvez até reutilizar o código do cliente no servidor.*

Quando o usuário acessar a página padrão, `site.com`, ele será servido com o `index_en_us.html`. Porém, o conteúdo será traduzido no lado do cliente, baseado no idioma do navegador.

Você também poderia ler o cabeçalho de `Accept-Language`, no servidor, e dar um conteúdo com o melhor idioma. Porém, muitos CDNs (como o CloudFlare) não respeitam o `Vary`. Então, mesmo que você retorne um cabeçalho de `Vary: Accept-Language`, para indicar que o conteúdo é outro dependendo do `Accept-Language`, eles continuam dando o mesmo resultado para qualquer requisição. Por isso, eu preferi por enviar o conteúdo padrão e o cliente, no Javascript, traduzir. A tradução no lado do cliente é positiva por ser imediata, então o usuário pode alternar o idioma quando quiser, sem ter que esperar.